# MD5 Hash returning different results in Python

Tags: python, json, hash, md5

For a class assignment, I'm supposed to grab the contents of a file, compute the MD5 hash and store it in a separate file. Then I'm supposed to be able to check the integrity by comparing the MD5 hash. I'm relatively new to Python and JSON, so I thought I'd try to tackle those things with this assignment as opposed to going with something I already know.

Anyway, my program reads from a file, creates a hash, and stores that hash into a JSON file just fine. The problem comes in with my integrity checking. When I return the results of the computed hash of the file, it's different from what is recorded in the JSON file even though no changes have been made to the file. Below is an example of what is happening and I pasted my code as well. Thanks in advance for the help.

For example: These are the contents of my JSON file

Content: b'I made a file to test the md5\n'

digest: 1e8f4e6598be2ea2516102de54e7e48e

This is what is returned when I try to check the integrity of the exact same file (no changes made to it):
Content: b'I made a file to test the md5\n'

digest: ef8b7bf2986f59f8a51aae6b496e8954

```
import hashlib
import json
import os
import fnmatch
from codecs import open


#opens the file, reads/encodes it, and returns the contents (c)
def read_the_file(f_location):
    with open(f_location, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        c = f.read()

    f.close()
    return c


def scan_hash_json(directory_content):
    for f in directory_content:
        location = argument + "/" + f
        content = read_the_file(location)
        comp_hash = create_hash(content)
        json_obj = {"Directory": argument, "Contents": {"filename": str(f),
                                                        "original string": str(content), "md5": str(comp_hash)}}
        location = location.replace(argument, "")
        location = location.replace(".txt", "")
        write_to_json(location, json_obj)


#scans the file, creates the hash, and writes it to a json file
def read_the_json(f):
    f_location = "recorded" + "/" + f
    read_json = open(f_location, "r")
    json_obj = json.load(read_json)
    read_json.close()
    return json_obj


#check integrity of the file
def check_integrity(d_content):
    #d_content = directory content
    for f in d_content:
        json_obj = read_the_json(f)
        text = f.replace(".json", ".txt")
        result = find(text, os.getcwd())
        content = read_the_file(result)
        comp_hash = create_hash(content)
        print("content: " + str(content))
        print(result)
        print(json_obj)
        print()
        print("Json Obj: " + json_obj['Contents']['md5'])
        print("Hash: " + comp_hash)


#find the file being searched for
def find(pattern, path):
    result = ""
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result = os.path.join(root, name)
    return result


#create a hash for the file contents being passed in
def create_hash(content):
    h = hashlib.md5()
    key_before = "reallyBad".encode('utf-8')
    key_after = "hashKeyAlgorithm".encode('utf-8')
    content = content.encode('utf-8')
    h.update(key_before)
    h.update(content)
    h.update(key_after)
    return h.hexdigest()


#write the MD5 hash to the json file
def write_to_json(arg, json_obj):
    arg = arg.replace(".txt", ".json")
    storage_location = "recorded/" + str(arg)
    write_file = open(storage_location, "w")
    json.dump(json_obj, write_file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    write_file.close()

#variable to hold status of user (whether they are done or not)
working = 1
#while the user is not done, continue running the program
while working == 1:
    print("Please input a command. For help type 'help'. To exit type 'exit'")

    #grab input from user, divide it into words, and grab the command/option/argument
    request = input()
    request = request.split()

    if len(request) == 1:
        command = request[0]
    elif len(request) == 2:
        command = request[0]
        option = request[1]
    elif len(request) == 3:
        command = request[0]
        option = request[1]
        argument = request[2]
    else:
        print("I'm sorry that is not a valid request.\n")
        continue

    #if user inputs command 'icheck'...
    if command == 'icheck':
        if option == '-l':
            if argument == "":
                print("For option -l, please input a directory name.")
                continue

            try:
                dirContents = os.listdir(argument)
                scan_hash_json(dirContents)

            except OSError:
                print("Directory not found. Make sure the directory name is correct or try a different directory.")

        elif option == '-f':
            if argument == "":
                print("For option -f, please input a file name.")
                continue

            try:
                contents = read_the_file(argument)
                computedHash = create_hash(contents)
                jsonObj = {"Directory": "Default", "Contents": {
                    "filename": str(argument), "original string": str(contents), "md5": str(computedHash)}}

                write_to_json(argument, jsonObj)
            except OSError:
                print("File not found. Make sure the file name is correct or try a different file.")

        elif option == '-t':
            try:
                dirContents = os.listdir("recorded")
                check_integrity(dirContents)
            except OSError:
                print("File not found. Make sure the file name is correct or try a different file.")

        elif option == '-u':
            print("gonna update stuff")
        elif option == '-r':
            print("gonna remove stuff")

    #if user inputs command 'help'...
    elif command == 'help':
        #display help screen
        print("Integrity Checker has a few options you can use. Each option "
              "must begin with the command 'icheck'. The options are as follows:")
        print("\t-l <directory>: Reads the list of files in the directory and computes the md5 for each one")
        print("\t-f <file>: Reads a specific file and computes its md5")
        print("\t-t: Tests integrity of the files with recorded md5s")
        print("\t-u <file>: Update a file that you have modified after its integrity has been checked")
        print("\t-r <file>: Removes a file from the recorded md5s\n")

    #if user inputs command 'exit'
    elif command == 'exit':
        #set working to zero and exit program loop
        working = 0

    #if anything other than 'icheck', 'help', and 'exit' are input...
    else:
        #display error message and start over
        print("I'm sorry that is not a valid command.\n")
```

Comment: Can you include your main() method, as well? Are you creating the hash json file, and then checking the integrity of the hash in one run of your application? Are you using the create_hash function to create the initial hash, and then again to verify it?

Comment: I included my main method. The json file is created already. When the user inputs "icheck -t" the program goes through the directory storing the .json files, looks for the .txt file, computes the hash, and compares it to what is inside the .json file.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms my suspicions. See my answer below for what I believe the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you defining h, the md5 object being used in this method?

```
 #create a hash for the file contents being passed in
 def create_hash(content):
     key_before = "reallyBad".encode('utf-8')
     key_after = "hashKeyAlgorithm".encode('utf-8')
     print("Content: " + str(content))
     h.update(key_before)
     h.update(content)
     h.update(key_after)
     print("digest: " + str(h.hexdigest()))
     return h.hexdigest()
```

My suspicion is that you're calling create_hash twice, but using the same md5 object in both calls. That means the second time you call it, you're really hashing "reallyBad*file contents*hashkeyAlgorithmreallyBad*file contents*hashKeyAlgorithm". You should create a new md5 object inside of create_hash to avoid this.

**Edit**: Here is how your program runs for me after making this change:

```
 Please input a command. For help type 'help'. To exit type 'exit'
 icheck -f ok.txt Content: this is a test

 digest: 1f0d0fd698dfce7ce140df0b41ec3729 Please input a command. For
 help type 'help'. To exit type 'exit' icheck -t Content: this is a
 test

 digest: 1f0d0fd698dfce7ce140df0b41ec3729 Please input a command. For
 help type 'help'. To exit type 'exit'
```

**Edit #2:**
Your scan_hash_json function also has a bug at the end of it. You're removing the .txt suffix from the file, and calling write_to_json:

```
def scan_hash_json(directory_content):
        ...
        location = location.replace(".txt", "")
        write_to_json(location, json_obj)
```

However, write_to_json is expecting the file to end in .txt:

```
def write_to_json(arg, json_obj):
    arg = arg.replace(".txt", ".json")
```

If you fix that, I think it should do everything as expected...

Comment: I see what you're saying. I moved my `h = hashlib.md5()` to inside of the create_hash function and though the hashes are different now, they still don't match the way they should. Thanks for you input though, I was definitely making a bad error by doing it the previous way.

Comment: Do you just need to clear the .json files and try again? Because I just tested your program after making that change, and it works fine for me. See the edit in my answer for the output.

Comment: It's working correctly for the -f option, but not for my -l option. So I must be doing something wrong within my scan_hash_json function. I have to drive to school really quick, but I'm going to take a peek again as soon as I get there.

Comment: I gave you best answer because your fixes helped me a ton with fixing the errors in my code, so thank you! I caught that error I made within my scan_hash_json function too. My biggest issue was that my find function was going into my directory which contained the .json files and creating hashes for the contents of those files. So it was throwing my whole program out of wack. I fixed that up. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible problems you are facing:

1. for hash computation is computing from a binary representation of a string
2. unless you work only with ASCII encoding, the same international character e.g. č has different representations in the UTF-8 or Unicode encoding.

To consider:

1. If you need UTF-8 or Unicode, [normalize](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) first your content before you save it or calculate a hash
2. For testing purposes compare content binary representation.
3. use UTF-8 only for IO operations, `codecs.open` does all conversion
   for you

   from codecs import open
   with open('yourfile', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
     decoded_content = f.read()

Comment: This helps, but it's still broken. In order for this to compile I had to add `content = content.encode('utf-8')` within my create_hash function. Once I did that, now 2 of my hashes match and the other 3 are still broken. Thanks for your input, it got me a little closer to fixing this :)